# Updating the UI Thread without a task to continue on

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I currently have a Task that starts a method and loops a given amount of times. Each loop I want to simulate some work being done (Thread.Sleep) and update the UI afterwards. The only way I currently know to update the UI thread is with task continuation. My problem here is that in the method, I dont have a task to continue on.

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.pbStatus.Value = 0;
        Task.Run(() => StartProcess(100));

        //Show message box to demonstrate that StartProcess()
        //is running asynchronously
        MessageBox.Show("Called after async process started.");
    }

    // Called Asynchronously
    private void StartProcess(int max)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        {
            //Do some work
            Thread.Sleep(10);

            //How to correctly update UI?
            this.lblOutput.Text = i.ToString();
            this.pbStatus.Value = i;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to refactor this code to work using only the TPL? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1.system-iprogress-t--report?view=netframework-4.7.2) to report progress back to the UI thread.

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.pbStatus.Value = 0;

    //Setup the progress reporting
    var progress = new Progress<int>(i =>
    {
        this.lblOutput.Text = i.ToString();
        this.pbStatus.Value = i;
    });
    Task.Run(() => StartProcess(100, progress));

    //Show message box to demonstrate that StartProcess()
    //is running asynchronously
    MessageBox.Show("Called after async process started.");
}

// Called Asynchronously
private void StartProcess(int max, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
    {
        //Do some work
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        //Report your progress
        progress.Report(i);
    }
}
```