# Having trouble refactoring synchronous app to use async/await (C#)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to refactor an existing synchronous app into one that uses Async/Await. This WPF app was written originally using a BackgroundWorker thread calling a bunch of synchronous methods. I went down to the deepest level and worked my way up, converting these methods to async, using await Task.Run(()..) on some of them that didn't seem to be [taking too long](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html).

I am stuck on something though. I want to pass in an IProgress parameter, to be able to get feedback into the UI -- and the last, deepest method, the one that takes the longest to execute, is written this way:

```
public static Task<bool> SaveToFileAsync(string filePath)
{
    return Task.Run(() => SaveToFile(filePath));

    /*
        SaveToFile calls into an unmanaged dll that uses a few loops and writes
        to file using fopen/fwrite...
    */
}

private async void CreateObjectAndSaveToFile(/*IProgress progress*/)
{
    List<Task> SaveFileTaskArray = new List<Task>();
    int index = 0;

    foreach (...)
    {
        // 
        {
            DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime();
            //Start Async Task to save this SomeThing to file
            SaveFileTaskArray.Add(SaveToFileAsync(fileName));
        }
        index++;
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(SaveFileTaskArray);
}
```

Now if I call CreateObjectAndSaveToFile() on the UI side like so:

```
await CreateObjectAndSaveToFile();
```

I get the desired effect - UI is responsive and files get saved one by one (can be 10-20 files). But for completeness, I'd like to add a progress bar to this (and therefore adding that IProgress parameter all the way down).

I'm not sure how I can do that.

Comment: Have you tried passing some callback or events then listen from the high level to that event or callback ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53287656/7444103) (quite simple and similar to the code you already have) and its duplicate, which uses a *proprietary* implementation. Many other examples are available.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to use IProgress, but that wasn't the question. The problem is that at the end (even though there is a loop there), I'm awaiting a Task.WhenAll, and I don't have an indication on when a single save task have been completed.

Comment: Modify `SaveToFile(filePath)` then, so you can update `IProgress` from there. You have a parallel-ish progress here, you could updated the progress `+1` per file, setting the progress max value to the number of files you're about to copy. I have no idea what `DoSomethingThatTakesSomeTime();` is doing, what takes more time to complete and the progress of what you want to notify. If the final file copy operation is enough, go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in the comments that you know how to use `IProgress` already. So if you want report progress as each task finishes, you can use [`WhenAny()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) instead of `WhenAll()`, and remove each task from the list as it finishes. Something like this:

```
while (SaveFileTaskArray.Count > 0) {
    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(SaveFileTaskArray);

    SaveFileTaskArray.Remove(finishedTask);

    //Report progress of how many are left
    progress.Report(SaveFileTaskArray.Count);
}
```

The Microsoft documentation actually has a whole article about this, if you want to read more: [Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete)

Comment: Just be aware that this technique is unsuitable for huge numbers of tasks. You get significant overhead when the tasks become more than 3,000 or so.